# Speakers playing faint white noise when turned on

Tags: 13.04, sound, speakers, noise

My speakers are constantly playing a a faint white noise when they are turned on, it only started happening when i put Ubuntu on it as well. My machine is a new Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon. Other questions similar to mine aren't helping either. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I will try to help. Do you have a soundcard? If you do, type alsamixer in the Terminal. There you will be able to tune it a little, and hopefully get rid of the white noise.

If that doesn't work, you might try upgrading your kernel. I am still learning, but these are some suggestions that I have discovered.